# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n\frac{\ln x}{c_n+x\ln x}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $c_n$ be an unbounded sequence: $c_n\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$

Find the value of the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n\frac{\ln x}{c_n+x\ln x}\,dx$$

What I managed to find was the fact that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{c_n+x\ln x}=0$$
I was thinking  that the limit is going to be $0$, but I have to prove it still. Maybe it is not and I am wrong I do not know for sure.

I denoted
$$I(n)=\int_1^n\frac{\ln x}{c_n+x\ln x}\,dx$$

I was thinking of finding a recurrence formula for this integral, Though, I could not be able to make any significant progress.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you want the specific case $c_n=n\log n$ or the more general $c_n \to \infty$?

Comment: I would want the general case, but maybe a particular case might help with the general case. If you have a solution for that particular case I would be grateful if you post it so as to have an idea how the general case might be solved.

Comment: If ${c_n\over n\log n}\to \infty$ the limit is equal $0.$ So the case $c_n=n\log n$ is interesting.

Comment: Why is the limit equal with zero for $\frac{c_n}{n\log _n}\rightarrow \infty $?

Comment: @Henry would you like to share the case $c_n=n\log _n$ in case you know it?

Comment: Following the comments of Henry and Ryszard: from
$$\frac{\log x}{c_n + x\log x}\mathbb{1}_{(1,n]}(x)\leq \frac{\log n}{c_n}\mathbb{1}_{(1,n]}(x)$$
we have
$$\int^n_1\frac{\log x}{c_n + x\log x}\,dx\leq \frac{n\log n}{c_n}$$
Thus, of $\lim_n\frac{c_n}{n\log n}=\infty$, the case discussed in the comments has $0$ limit.

Comment: It might be helpful to consider the equivalent integral: $$\int_{1/n}^1\frac{\ln x}{x\ln x-c_n\cdot x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 5):

As @Ryszard Szwarc mentioned in the comment, if $\frac{c_n}{n\ln n}\to\infty,\,\,\lim_{n→∞} \int _1^n\frac{\ln\:x}{c_n\:+\:x\:\ln x}dx=0$, and the most interesting is the case $c_n=n\ln n$.

So, we want to find $\lim_{n→∞} I(n)=\lim_{n→∞}\int _1^n\frac{\ln\:x}{n\ln n\:+\:x\:\ln x}dx$. Making the substitution $x=e^t$
$$I(n)=\int _1^n\frac{\ln\:x}{n\ln n\:+\:x\:\ln x}dx=\int_0^{\ln n}\frac{te^t}{n\ln n+e^t t}dt$$
Making another substitution $t=s\ln n$
$$I(n)=\frac{\ln n}{n}\int_0^1\frac{sn^s}{1+\frac{s}{n^{1-s}}}ds$$
As $\frac{s}{n^{1-s}}\leqslant1$, we can decompose the denominator into the series:
$$I(n)=\frac{\ln n}{n}\int_0^1n^ss\big(1-sn^{s-1}+s^2n^{2s-2}-s^3n^{3s-3}+-...\big)ds$$
Integrating by part, we get the terms with the different rate of convergence, for example:
$$\int_0^1sn^sds=\frac{1}{\ln^2n}\int_0^{\ln n}se^sds=\frac{1}{\ln^2n}\big(n\ln n-n\big)=\frac{n}{\ln n}-\frac{n}{\ln^2 n}$$
The same story happens to all the terms; only the first ones will give a non-zero limit at $n\to\infty$.
Therefore, keeping only these main terms
$$I(n)=\frac{\ln n}{n}\Big(\frac{1}{\ln^2n}\int_0^{\ln n}e^xxdx-\frac{1}{n\ln^3n}\frac{1}{2^3}\int_0^{2\ln n}e^xx^2dx+\frac{1}{n^2\ln^4n}\frac{1}{3^4}\int_0^{3\ln n}e^xx^3dx-+...\Big)$$
The pattern is clear. Integrating by part and keeping only first terms of every integral
$$I(n)=\frac{\ln n}{n}\Big(\frac{1}{\ln^2n}n\ln n-\frac{1}{n\ln^3n}\frac{1}{2^3}2^2n^2\ln^2n+\frac{1}{n^2\ln^4n}\frac{1}{3^4}3^3n^3\ln^3n-+...\Big)+O\Big(\frac{1}{\ln n}\Big)$$
$$\Rightarrow\,\,\boxed{\,\,\lim_{n\to\infty} I(n)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+-...=\ln 2=0.693147...\,\,}$$
The numeric evaluation of the limit confirms this conclusion:
$$\int _1^n\frac{\ln\:x}{n\ln n\:+\:x\:\ln x}dx\,\Big|_{n=10^{300}}=0.692143...$$
though the rate of convergence, of course, is monstrously low :)

It is not difficult to evaluate in the same way the second and third terms of the asymptotics. I got
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=\ln2-\frac{\ln2}{\ln n}+\Big(\ln2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\Big)\frac{1}{\ln^2n}+O\Big(\frac{1}{\ln^3n}\Big)\,\,}$$

$\mathbf{PS}$

I checked numerically the revised asymptotics. It seems it works!
$$\int _1^n\frac{\ln\:x}{n\ln n\:+\:x\:\ln x}dx\,\Big|_{n=1000}=0.590148...$$
Asymptotics gives
$$I(n)\sim\ln2-\bigg(\frac{\ln2}{\ln n}+\Big(\ln2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\Big)\frac{1}{\ln^2n}\bigg)\,\bigg|_{n=1000}=0.590093...$$

Comment: You may want to stick with either $c_n$ or $C_n$ at the beginning.

Comment: @Gary , thank you. Correcting

Comment: Also in the middle of the post you give the expansion for $I(n)$ but then you say it equals to its limit as $n \to \infty$. Since you keep only the first term of each integral, the expansion is not equal to $I(n)$.

Comment: @Gary, thank you for catching this. Also correcting

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that we have the following inequalities:

$$ \log\biggl(1 + \varliminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log n}{c_n}\biggr)
\leq \varliminf_{n\to\infty} I(n)
\leq \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} I(n)
\leq \log\biggl(1 + \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\log n}{c_n}\biggr)
$$

---

Let $g : [0, \infty) \to [1, \infty)$ be the inverse of $x \mapsto x \log x$ for $x \geq 1$, that is, $g$ solves the functional equation

$$ g(t) \log g(t) = t $$

(In fact, we can write $g(t) = t/W(t)$ where $W(t)$ is the Lambert W-function. However, this observation is not needed here.) Then by substituting $t = x \log x$, or equivalently, $x = g(t)$, and noting that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}
= \frac{g'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t}{g(t)}
= \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{g(t)(\log g(t) + 1)}
= \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t + g(t)} $$

we have

\begin{align*}
I(n)
= \int_{1}^{n} \frac{x \log x}{c_n + x \log x} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}
= \int_{0}^{n \log n} \frac{t}{c_n + t} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t + g(t)}
\end{align*}

Writing $\rho_n = (n \log n) / c_n$ and substituting $t = c_n u$,

\begin{align*}
I(n)
&= \int_{0}^{\rho_n} \frac{u}{1 + u} \cdot \frac{1}{u + g(c_n u)/c_n} \, \mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

Now, let $ \displaystyle \alpha = \varliminf_{n\to\infty} \rho_n$ and $ \displaystyle 
\beta = \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \rho_n$. Then

$$ \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} I(n)
\leq \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\rho_n} \frac{u}{1 + u} \cdot \frac{1}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u
= \varlimsup_{n\to\infty} \log(1+\rho_n)
= \log(1+\beta) \tag{1} $$

On the other hand, together with the fact that $g(t) \ll t$ and the Fatou's lemma,

\begin{align*}
\varliminf_{n\to\infty} I(n)
&\geq \int_{0}^{\infty} \varliminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{u}{1 + u} \cdot \frac{1}{u + g(c_n u)/c_n} \mathbf{1}_{[0, \rho_n]}(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u}{u+1} \cdot \frac{1}{u} \mathbf{1}_{[0, \alpha)}(u) \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \log(1+\alpha) \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 This fully addresses the question

Answer (score 3):

This is not an entire solution, but a long comment.

Following the comments of Henry and Ryszard: from
$$\frac{\log x}{c_n + x\log x}\mathbb{1}_{(1,n]}(x)\leq \frac{\log n}{c_n}\mathbb{1}_{(1,n]}(x)$$
we have
$$\int^n_1\frac{\log x}{c_n + x\log x}\,dx\leq \frac{n\log n}{c_n}$$
Thus, of $\lim_n\frac{c_n}{n\log n}=\infty$, the case discussed in the comments has $0$ limit.

For the general case, the limit if exists, may not be $0$
$$\frac{\log(m-1)}{c_n+m\log m}\leq \int^m_{m-1}\frac{\log x}{c_n + x\log x}\,dx  \leq\frac{\log m}{c_n+ (m-1)\log (m-1)}\leq \frac{\log m}{c_n}$$
adding all terms for $2\leq m\leq n$ yields
$$\frac{\log((n-1)!)}{c_n+n\log n}\leq\sum^n_{m=2}\frac{\log(m-1)}{c_n+m\log m}\leq \int^n_1\frac{\log x}{c_n+x\log x}\,dx\leq \frac{1}{c_n}\log(n!)$$

Comment: Hi, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440492/prove-or-disprove-that-x-0-in-operatornamecl-y-iff-there-exists-a-sequence#4440492), please?