# Prove or disprove that $x_0\in\operatorname{cl} Y$ iff there exists a sequence $x_n$ in $Y\subseteq X$ converging to $x_0$ when $X$ is sequential.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

The following is an exercise from Elementos de Topología General by Ángel Tamariz Mascarúa and Fidel Casarrubias Segura.

First a couple of definitions:

> **Definiton** A topological space $X$ is Frechét-Urysohn if for very $A\subset X$ and $x\in\overline{A}$, there is a sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset A$ that converges to $x$.

> **Definition** A topological space $X$ is said to be sequential if for any $Y\subset X$,  $Y$ is not closed if and only if there exists $x\in X\setminus Y$ and a sequence $(x_n: n\in\Bbb N)\subset Y$ with converges to $x$.

Problem 7 and  8 in that textbook say:

- 7: Check that a first countable topological space is Frechét-Uryshohn, and that this property is inherited by any subspace of $X$.
- 8(a) Show that every closed subset of a sequential space is also sequential, and that every Fréchet-Uryshohn space is sequential.
- 8(b) Check that propositions 3.41 and 3.42 (below) hold if the assumption *first countable* is replaced by *sequential*.

---

Here are the statement of the Propositions mentioned in the problem:

> Proposition 3.41: If $X$ is first countable and $E\subset X$, then $x\in \overline{E}$ (closure of $E$) iff there is a sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset E$ that converges to $x$.

> Proposition 3.42: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces. If $X$ is first countable and $x\in X$, then  $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ with $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}x$, $f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}y$ in $Y$.

---

So I am really confused about the preceding theorem becasue if it is was true then it seem to me it would prove that a sequential space is a Fréchet-Uryshon space but as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/754646/736008) showed this is false. So first of all to follow I put a direct reference of the text I mentioned hoping I understood bad Spanish text.

[image]

Anyway I tried to prove the statement and surprisingly it seems true. So to follow my proof attempt.

> *proof* $\,8$.b.$1.\,\,$
>
> So if $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence in $Y$ converging to $x_0$ then by convergence definition for any neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$ there exist $n_V\in\Bbb N$ such that
> $$
> x_n\in V
> $$
> for all $n\ge n_V$ but if $x_n$ is in $Y$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ then this means that $V\cap Y$ is not empty, that is $x_0$ is adherent to $Y$.

> Conversely let be $x_0\in\operatorname{cl}Y$ and we let use sequentiality to make a sequence on $Y$ converging to $x_0$. So if $x_0$ is an isolated point of $Y$ then trivially the position
> $$
> x_n:=x
> $$
> for all $n\in\Bbb N$ defines sequence in $Y$ converging to $x_0$ so we suppose that $x_0$ is an accumulation point for $Y$. Now if $x_0$ is an accumulation point for $Y$ then as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440378/prove-or-disprove-that-operatornamecl-big-operatornamecl-y-setminus-x-0) showed the identity
> $$
> \operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}\big)=\operatorname{cl} Y
> $$
> holds and thus we conclude that $\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}$ is not closed so that **by sequentiality** there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in $\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}$ converging to $x\notin \operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}$. So if $x_n$ is in $\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ then by the first implication $x$ must be in $\operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}\big)$ that is in $\operatorname{cl} Y$ and so $x$ must be equal to $x_0$ because the unique element of $\operatorname{cl} Y$ not in $\operatorname{cl}Y\setminus\{x_0\}$ is $x_0$.

So is the proposition $8$.b.$1$ true? if it is true then is the proof I gave correct? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135984/discussion-on-question-by-antonio-maria-di-mauro-prove-or-disprove-that-x-0-in).

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: The sequential analogue of $3.41$ is false. Let $X$ be the [Arens space](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/) as described in Dan Ma’s Topology Blog; $X$ is sequential. Let $Y=\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$; then $\infty\in\operatorname{cl}Y$, but there is no sequence in $Y$ converging to $\infty$. And this example shows where your argument goes astray: taking $x_n=n$, we do have $x_n\in(\operatorname{cl}Y)\setminus\{\infty\}$, and $\lim_nx_n=\infty$, but the points $x_n$ aren’t in $Y$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I see. However is the analogue of $3.42$ true?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Yes; in fact that property [characterizes sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Sequential_spaces).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, all clear now: thanks very much for your assistance!!! See you soon.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this to summarize my previous comments and Brian Scott's insightful comments.

Indeed, there must be a typo in the textbook to which you are referring.
You may want to contact one of the [authors](https://www.fciencias.unam.mx/directorio/33029) to see if they keep tabs on errata. What I think problem 8 should have ask is to check whether propositions 3.41 and 3.42 hold when *first countable* is replaced by *sequential*.

---

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is has the Frechét-Urysohn property. If $A\subset X$ is not closed, then there exists  $a\in \overline{A}\setminus A$. Consequently there exists a sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset A$ such that $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$. This implies that $(X,\tau)$ is sequential.

Prop 3.41 implies that every first countable space has the Frechét-Urysohn property.

---

8b:

- Regarding Prop. 3.41.
  As you pointed out, proposition 3.41 does not hold for general sequential spaces. Otherwise, every sequential space would have the Frechét-Urysohn-Urysohn property; however, there are Frechét-Urysohn-Urysohn spaces that are not sequential ([the Arens space](https://www.fciencias.unam.mx/directorio/33029))
- Regarding Prop 3.42. Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is sequential and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a map such that for any $x\in X$ and sequence  $x_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$ implies $f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$. If $f$ is not continuous, then there is  a closed set $F\subset Y$  such that $f^{-1}(F)$ is not closed in $X$. Then, there is $x\in X\setminus f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)$ and a sequence $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset f^{-1}(F)$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$. Then, $(f(x_n):n\in\mathbb{N})\subset F$, and by assumption,  $f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$. Then $f(x)\in F$ contradicting the fact that $x\notin f^{-1}(F)$. This shows that Proposition 3.42 holds if first countable is replaced by sequential.

Comment: Okay, only a last question. In the textbook the proof of $3.42$ for first countable spaces is given pointwise: that is, if $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$ then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$ such that $f[U]\nsubseteq V$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and thus using this the authors make a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converging to $x_0$ whose immage $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge to $f(x_0)$.

Comment: Now instead you are proving this now not pointwise because only if $f$ is not **globally** continuous in $X$ there exists an closed set whose preimage under $f$ is not closed, that is you are proving that if **all** $x\in X$ are such that $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to x$ then $f$ is continuous in $X$, right?

Comment: I do not believe I want edit your answer: indeed in the comment above I only asked a question about your proof to be sure I understand it because I am autodidact, that's all. So did you proved that if **all** $x\in X$ are such that $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ then $f$ is continuous in $X$? Is  your proof valid also when only some $x\in X$ is such that $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: What I proved is that if $X$ is sequential, a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff and only of for any $x\in X$ and $(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}x$, $f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$. Continuity at a single point seems more challenging. You may ask a precise question on this point to Brian M. Scott, we is an expert in Post set topology amongst other things.

Comment: Okay, all clear now. Anyway I do not know if I really interested about continuity of a single point: probably if in many texts (e.g. Engelking) there is the proof you gave then the pointwise continuity fails. Anyway thanks very much for your assistance: you was very kind with me on the contrary to my professors and thus I am sorry I you did not recived points by my upovote and approvation. So thanks really: see you soon.